# How to use BorderLayout within a dialogue box?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, jpanel

I'm having trouble figuring out how to move and image to a different place in the window. I read about BorderLayout but I'm not sure how to implement it. I want the image to be above the text area but i dont know how i woudl go about it within a dialogue box.

```
b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        /**
         * Displays the arraylist.
         */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (cars.size()>0){

                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Window.class.getResource("/car.png"));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


                for(int i=0; i < cars.size(); i++) {
                    sb.append("Car " + (i+1) + ": " + cars.get(i) + "\n");
                }

                Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14);
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(sb.toString());
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea); 
                textArea.setFont(font);
                textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                textArea.setLineWrap(true);
                textArea.setEditable(false);
                textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true); 
                scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension( 100, 125 ));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scrollPane, "Inventory", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, icon);
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No cars available in inventory", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }


        }

    });
```

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need an additional JPanel with a border layout. To that container you would add the icon to the North and the scroll pane to the center like this.

```
JPanel contents = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

JLabel carImage = new JLabel(icon);

contents.add(carImage, BorderLayout.NORTH);
contents.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, contents, "Inventory", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Produces something like this:

[image]